# Wix and MSM confusion

Tags: c#, wix

I am working on a project that accepts the Wix data from decompiling an MSI, and incorporates the source file path table that was exported from Wise for Windows Installer.  The only problem I am running into is that Wix is looking for a directory for the files that were included in the Merge Modules (I think).  I want to check if the missing files are in the merge module and then give Wix that path to use.  The BIG problem is that I need to do this all dynamically as the program is running.  I.E. open the MSM and check if a file exists within.  Is this possible?  If so any help, guidance, or rays of hope that could be given would be priceless! Thanks in advance!

EDIT::
I should probably add that I am writing this program in C# with .NET 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Installer databases (such as msm and msi files) can be inspected with the **Deployment Tools Foundation** (also known as "DTF") libraries. These libraries are the managed wrappers for the windows installer SDK. They are part of the [wix project](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).

If you have wix 3.0 installed, you can find the DTF assemblies in `C:\program files\Windows Installer XML v3\sdk`.

The documentation can be found in `C:\Program Files\Windows Installer XML v3\doc\` in the files `dtf.chm` and `dtfapi.chm`.

Comment: That has thrown me in the right direction.  Thanks!  I was starting to get worried that no one had an answer :P